# Mobile Navigation BG Color / Misfiring Hamburger Menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a few items that I need a workaround for on my clients Wordpress site. I have this line of code that I'm trying to override and make transparent, however, it keeps reverting back to the blue from the original style.css.

**Issue #1:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-transparent fixed-top navbar-expand-lg justify-content-between px-md-5 py-4 fullwidth-container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" role="navigation">
```

I would like to isolate and take it from:

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
.navbar-dark.bg-transparent {
    background-color: #2f5be7 !important;
}
```

to this:

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
.navbar-dark.bg-transparent {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

**Issue #2**

The mega menu isn't rendering properly on Android. The actual sub-menu is supposed to have a www.dwellwellco.com/services page, however, the drop down renders as # and only serves up the sub-category pages.

**Issue #3**

As it relates to the Mega Menu on Android when you click on any of the other pages. The hamburger menu doesn't open on initial click. You have to click quite a few times (or the menu may not open at all.

Thank you for any help!

---

**Site URL for reference:**
www.dwellwellco.com

Answer (score 0):

About **Issue #1**:

> however, it keeps reverting back to the blue from the original style.css.

You could [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), set the parent theme stylesheet as a dependency of your child theme stylesheet to ensure that it loads after that.

Example provided by [WordPress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet):

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
```

And then add your CSS rules, i.e.

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
.navbar-dark.bg-transparent {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

in your child theme's `style.css`